# Create mysql table with dates as column header

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to make an Android APP for attendance recording of students in class.
How to create a MY SQL table with dates as the column name.
For example , I want the column headers as `2016-01-01`, `2016-01-02`, `2016-01-03` ... `2020-12-31`.

This table will have the first column which enters the name of students & their attendance PRESENT or ABSENT for each date column.

Comment: Dont even THINK of doing this. Store this information in a seperate table. Think about how you are going to process this table after you store a few weeks of data???

Comment: If you think this through then a student that does a 3 year course will require roughly 600 columns in this table.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359654/important-database-designing-rules-which-I-fo

Answer (score 0):

You can update the db version every day and use the callback

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN .....");
    }
}
```

Anyway I suggest you using three tables, one for the students and one for the dates and the last one to create a relations N-N between users and the dates.